# ngFor cant use ion-input ? when type one word it will lose focus

Tags: angular, ionic5

my html is simple like this

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of editLists,index as i">
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="editLists[i]"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

 <ion-input [(ngModel)]="foo"></ion-input>
```

it'ok type words when ion-input outside ngFor;
but when inside it will lose focus when i type one word
how?
many thanks

Comment: Replacae `<ion-list>` with `<ion-list item-content>`

Comment: @MFuatNUROĞLU hello, item-content webstorm it shows a custom attribute

Answer (score 4):

Use [trackBy](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#properties) along with ngFor to avoid re rendering input whenever input changes.

**component.html**

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of editLists,index as i;trackBy:trackEditList">
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="editLists[i]"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**component.ts**

```
trackEditList(index,item){
    return index;
}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tags-input-unexdh)

Comment: thank u ;
by the way [(ngModel)]="item" it will cause error  item is a readonly value why?

Comment: you can't bind local reference variable to ngModel. that's why  [(ngModel)]="item" is throwing error.